# Using SQLAlchemy to join with a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

In postgres, such a thing is possible:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
JOIN stored_procedure() ON (some_table.id = stored_procedure.id)
```

Is it possible to create this statement using SQLAlchemy core? (If so, then how?)

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in the [SQLAlchemy Docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#functions) (half way down the section on functions):

```
stored_procedure = (select([column('id'), column('result_column')])
    .select_from(func.stored_procedure())).alias()

conn.execute(select([stored_procedure.c.result_column, some_table.c.other_column])
    .select_from(some_table.join(stored_procedure, stored_procedure.c.id == some_table.c.id)))
```